# Trying to simulate LEAD() Window Function in MS Access

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I am trying to simulate the `LEAD()` Window Function in MS Access (which doesn't natively support `LEAD()`) in order to access data in rows further down in the result set. I know that this would be a piece of cake with MySQL v8+ and/or Oracle SQL but I am stuck with using MS Access.

I am trying to use a correlated subquery but the results are not correct or consistent based on the desired sorting order.

Table schema design is as follows:

[image]

The sort order is based on the `Station` column in `ASC` order.

Here is the query I am currently trying:

```
select m1.Point_No, 
m1.MatKey,
(select min(m12.MatKey) FROM tblMagicTwo AS m12 WHERE
m12.MatKey > m1.MatKey
) AS m2lead, m1.PID, m1.Station, m1.Eqstation, m1.SlopeStation, m1.Id
FROM tblMagicTwo AS m1
ORDER BY m1.Station ASC;
```

But am getting inconsistent results as I am trying to *inspect* the next rows' `MatKey` column value:

```
Point_No MatKey m2lead  PID  Station                Eqstation       SlopeStation        Id
721226302   73  74  82906   0.275726313821257   0.275726313821257   0.275726313821257   597
721226300   81      82907   1.48442023295109    2.36283843807831    2.36283843807831    638
713227078   77  78  82908   2.18997037280652    9.9467293919253     9.9467293919253     595
713227080   78  79  82909   3.08545066237174    11.0723155394953    11.0723155394953    423
713227081   78  79  82910   9.33109914739401    17.3196008698177    17.3196008698177    424
713227083   74  75  82911   53.7173258962502    61.7132360667789    61.7132360667789    644
713227085   78  79  82912   55.3780482705102    63.3776892090905    63.3776892090905    425
713227087   78  79  82913   77.3887410356183    85.3911013026298    85.3911013026298    426
707227106   78  79  82914   119.468610914743    127.470973510659    127.470973510659    427
729229001   78  79  82915   161.769573893431    169.771938974515    169.771938974515    428
707227108   78  79  82916   204.170556488776    212.172924049165    212.172924049165    429
729229002   78  79  82917   246.672990348719    254.67596516223     254.67596516223     441
707227110   78  79  82918   289.105420505305    297.109001433908    297.109001433908    431
729229003   78  79  82919   331.503486839664    339.50842620893     339.50842620893     422
707227112   78  79  82920   373.69149560963     381.6977857411      381.6977857411      433
729229004   78  79  82921   416.290835559282    424.305230221448    424.305230221448    434
707227114   78  79  82922   457.759920718225    465.782205821409    465.782205821409    435
713227089   78  79  82923   500.034839156714    508.057782990513    508.057782990513    436
713227090   78  79  82924   510.155623514718    518.181001847242    518.181001847242    437
729229005   78  79  82925   552.654735270363    560.680473079938    560.680473079938    438
more rows...
```

The `m2lead` column (alias) is not returning the correct next rows' `MatKey` column value based of of the (desired) `Station` column `ASC` sorting order.

Yes, the `MatKey` column has duplicates and maybe this is the problem but I thought since the sorting is based off of the `Station` column, that wouldn't matter.

Where am I going wrong in the query?

Here are a few rows from `tblMagicTwo` sorted in `ASC` order on the `Station` column for reference in case needed.

```
Point_No MatKey PID     Station             Eqstation           SlopeStation        Id
721226302   73  82906   0.275726313821257   0.275726313821257   0.275726313821257   597
721226300   81  82907   1.48442023295109    2.36283843807831    2.36283843807831    638
713227078   77  82908   2.18997037280652    9.9467293919253     9.9467293919253     595
713227080   78  82909   3.08545066237174    11.0723155394953    11.0723155394953    423
713227081   78  82910   9.33109914739401    17.3196008698177    17.3196008698177    424
713227083   74  82911   53.7173258962502    61.7132360667789    61.7132360667789    644
713227085   78  82912   55.3780482705102    63.3776892090905    63.3776892090905    425
713227087   78  82913   77.3887410356183    85.3911013026298    85.3911013026298    426
707227106   78  82914   119.468610914743    127.470973510659    127.470973510659    427
729229001   78  82915   161.769573893431    169.771938974515    169.771938974515    428
707227108   78  82916   204.170556488776    212.172924049165    212.172924049165    429
729229002   78  82917   246.672990348719    254.67596516223     254.67596516223     441
707227110   78  82918   289.105420505305    297.109001433908    297.109001433908    431
729229003   78  82919   331.503486839664    339.50842620893     339.50842620893     422
more rows...
```

Thank you everyone for any help and pointers!

Answer (score 0):

Try including a unique field:

`m12.MatKey > m1.MatKey And m12.PID > m1.PID`

Comment: I tried using the `Id` column since it is AutoNumber (and Unique) but still inconsistent results.